# How change execlp to execv and run other commands then just 'ls'

Tags: c, pipe, output, execv

At the moment im running an HTML webserver that can run commands given to it through a text box and a submit button but i need to convert the `execlp` to `execv` and im not understanding the array portion of the `execv`. I tried to just make it `execv(command, command);` but it gives me a passing argument of incompatible pointer type issue. Also for some reason my execution will only run one word commands like `ls` and wont accept any flags either and im not quite sure why that is. Execution and parsing section of code below, can provide full code if needed.

**Exection.c**

```
char *parse(char *command){
    char * newCommand = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    int tgt = 0;
     newCommand = strstr(command, "/run?command=");
    newCommand = strtok(newCommand, " ");
    newCommand = newCommand + 13;
     for(int src = 0; src< strlen(newCommand); src++){
        if(newCommand[src] == '+')
        {
            newCommand[src] = ' ';
        }
        else if(newCommand[src] == '%')
        {
            newCommand[src] = ' ';
        }
        else if(newCommand[src] == '7')
        {
            newCommand[src] = ' ';
        }
        else if(newCommand[src] == 'C')
        {
            newCommand[src] = '|';
        }


    }

     return newCommand;
}

char * execution(char *command){

  int piper[2];
    size_t len = 0;
    pipe(piper);
  char* output =  malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    memset(output, '\0', 1000* sizeof(char));
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid != 0)// parent
        {
            wait(NULL);
            close(piper[1]);
      int n = sizeof(output);

            struct pollfd * poll_fd = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd));
             poll_fd->fd = piper[0];
             poll_fd->events = POLLIN;

            if(poll(poll_fd, 1, 0) == 1){ // pipe data check
            read(piper[0], output, 1000);
            }

        }
        else{

            close(1);
            dup(piper[1]);
            execlp(command, command, NULL);
        exit(1);
        }
                return output;
}

int main (void){
    int sockfd;
    int new_fd; 
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *serverinfo; 
    struct addrinfo *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addrsize;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int status;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); //makes struct empty 
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //IPv4 or v6 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //TCP type need 
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; //Fill in IP for us 


    //if can't get address info print error 
    if((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &serverinfo)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }


    for(p = serverinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(serverinfo);

    if(p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1){
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections....\n");

    while(1){
        addrsize = sizeof client_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addrsize);
        if(new_fd == -1){
            perror("Did not accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(client_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&client_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if(!fork()){
            close(sockfd);
            int bufsize = 1024;

            char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);
            recv(new_fd, buffer, bufsize, 0);
            send(new_fd, header, bufsize, 0);

            if(send(new_fd, execution(parse(buffer)), 1000, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: IMNSHO, you can't write a practical shell using `execl()` or `execlp()` because the argument lists to the `l`-exec functions are fixed at compile time and shell commands aren't.  You practically have to use `execv()` or one of its variants (`execve()`, `execvp()`, sometimes `execvpe()`) — the `v`-exec functions.  You create a null-terminated array of character pointers (rather like `argv` to `main()` — because that's what it becomes) and pass that to `execv()`:  given array `char **args;` appropriately initialized, `execv(args[0], args);` is the normal way to call `execv()`.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! I want to use execv() but entirely confused in this moment how to. So my code gets its command from the GET portion of the html page which it then parses and tokenizes out into `newCommand` which is then sent to `execution` to be run so is effectively in `command` but from there i cannot for the life of me figure out how to put the string in `command` into a `const * char []` to be able to send to `execv()`

Comment: Your code is confusing because there are comments, and a wholly unexpected `poll()` call.  I'm not sure where you're doing what.  You should concentrate on creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — or 'min-reprex' if the subject on MSO is to be believed; I sincerely hope it isn't! — which doesn't include commented out code.

Comment: will edit it up right now to make it far more readable!

Comment: You can create a normal `char **args = malloc((num_args + 1) * sizeof(args[0]));` and then make each element point to a string, the zeroth of which (`args[0]`) is the command name (or path to the command — which depends in part on whether you're using a `vp`-exec function), and the first is what will become `argv[1]` in the process, and `args[num_args] = NULL;`.  The `const` in the prototype says "`execX()` will not modify the argument" rather than that you must create something that's constant.

Comment: Will this method work @JonathanLeffler even if im not using `args[]` at all to get the command? As in the command given is not in anyway recieved through the command line argument terminal. Also how could i separate out the passed "command". When i attempt to split it on spaces to place it into an array or anything of the sort it throws warnings

Comment: Yes, of course — you can create the `args` array any way you like; I carefully avoided using `argv` to avoid confusion with the argument to the shell's `main()`.

Comment: hmmm i dont suppose i could ask you for an example i think i'm beginning to understand, or rather understanding the declaration of the `char **args` and how to use that but where im stuck is how to get each element to point to an individual part of the string inside the passed `char *command` as it doesnt appear theres a way to split it.

Comment: One of the bits of an MCVE that's missing is an example input — what is the input string that you want to execute?  Would you be better off with invoking `sh -c the-input-string` — which could go back to using `execlp()`, but probably wouldn't?  With some clarity on what the input looks like, an answer might be forthcoming.

Comment: ahhh okay perhaps i should include my entire code then it was just a lot so i thought that by not including it i would be  following the MCVE better. The example input which can be seen partially from the `parse` method is taken from the `GET` of an html string. This code is run with a webserver so i have an `html` page with a text box, in this text box ill type a command like `ls -l` and then in the search bar it says `localhost:3838/run?command=ls+-l` which i then tokenize out the `ls -l` and put that into `newCommand` which is then sent to execution as `command`

Comment: No; don't include the entire code.  Make it **Minimal** — and **Complete** enough that it can be compiled/run — and the fact that it can be run makes it **Verifiable**.  In particular, you could avoid the 'command reading' code; you could just create an array to hold the result, and pass that to the appropriate functions.  We don't need to see prompting and such like; that's not part of your problem.  We need `main()`, `parse()` and `execute()` — and probably that's all.  But an MCVE is not just code; there is also the input, and the expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: Understood, edited to include my main which should hopefully make this all make a bit more sense

Comment: Is the code in `parse()` meant to map `%7C` to `|` (or double-blank pipe)?  That's not very general, is it?  Other things than pipe (and blanks) can be `%`-escaped (URL encoded) in a URL.  Note that your `main()` might contain `char data[] = "/run?command=\"ls -l\"";` — or would it be `char data[] = "/run?command=&quot;ls+-l&quot";` — or could it use `%22` instead of `&quot`, or could it need to handle both?

Comment: yeah its meant to map `%7C` to `|` for piping purposes but i couldnt quite figure out how to convert the `%7C` to a `|` for piping, as from a URL `|` comes back to the terminal as `%7C` and if i put that in main then wouldnt i techinally be hard coding that variable and not getting it dynamically from the URL to work for other commands other then ls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `command` to be interpreted by a shell you will need to pass it as the an argument, something like:

```
const char *args[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", command};
execve("/bin/sh", args, NULL);
```

Beware that web shells are largely considered malware or future CVEs.

Comment: Seems to throw a warning of `expected char * const * but argument is of type const char **` for `args`

Comment: So you need to add a `const` after the `*`, @BretHasel?  Or remove the `const` before the `char`?  There should be a NULL after `command` in the initializer.  Removing the `const` works for me; it's what I'd use automatically.

Comment: i ended up fixing it it had to be a `char* const args[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", command};` but just wanted to let him know there was issues with his answer. Unfortunately didnt seem to help solve my issue though, it provides no output for some reason i dont quite understand and was currently trying to figure out

Comment: Now i just need to figure out how to get piping to work